# Restoring user data after app uninstall and reinstall in Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, authentication

I am developing a mobile app which involves Guest Login.
I want the users to easily restore the Guest Login. For example,

1. Install my app.
2. Use my app with Guest Login, without manual ID and password creation.
3. Uninstall my app.
4. Install my app again.
5. Use my app with the existing Guest Login again, without manual ID and password.

Even if the user's mobile app is not associated to Google nor Apple ID, I want the users can restore his or her Guest Login. Of course, resetting his or her mobile device is an exception.

I think Apple KeyChain Services, Google KeyStore API, Android `FileBackupHelper`, Android AAID may be the solution, but I am not sure of it.

Of course, I know that other ways than Guest Login such as Facebook or Google login, but my question is for the people without those login accounts.

Answer (score 2):

> Restoring user data after application uninstall and install again in Android

In **Android** you should have to use `android:allowBackup=true` in `<application>` tag which enables/disables backup

by default `allowBackup` is **true**. if you want to disable Auto Backup, set `android:allowBackup` to **false**. You may want to disable backups when your app can recreate its state through some other mechanism or when your application deals with sensitive information that should not be backed up.

```
<application ...
    android:allowBackup="true">
</app>
```

By using **Auto Backup** includes files in most of the directories that are assigned to your application by the system are:

- Shared preferences files.
- Files in the directory returned by `getFilesDir()`
- Files in the directory returned by getDatabasePath(String), which also includes files created with the SQLiteOpenHelper class.
- Files in directories created with getDir(String, int).
- Files on external storage in the directory returned by getExternalFilesDir(String).

You could use `sharepreferences` to store user details and get user data after reinstalling the application

> **Note:** this allowBackup Apps feature is available on **OS >= 6.0** and **API Level >= 23**

More about **[Auto Backup](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup.html)**

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Authentication might help you. This section includes an anonymous login process other than the normal social logins. Read the link below.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth